# Cache serializers django restframework

Tags: django, djangorestframework, cache

tengo un modelo serializado como en el siguiente ejemplo de codigo

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ['id', 'name']
```

Y esta es la que realmente devuelme el api

```
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cities = CitySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'cities']
```

Me pregunto si hay alguna forma de almacenar estos resultados en cache ya que la respuesta no va a cambiar o por si por defecto se cachea solo?

Este es mi Lista que retorno

```
class DepartmentList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Department.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DepartmentSerializer
```

para ello lo registro como sigue en el siguiente fragmento.

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('Departments', DepartmentList)
```

Agradezco si me puedes indicar si ya la cache esta activa por defecto o debo agregar condigo en alguna parte.

Answer (score 1):

Después de haber investigado con más minucia encontré que para cachear un ModelViewSet hay que primero que nada importar lo siguiente.

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
```

Luego en la case que tiene el modelo se debe  sobreescribir el metodo dispatch y agregar el decorador cache_page.
Como lo muestro a continuación:

```
class DepartmentList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Department.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DepartmentSerializer

    @method_decorator(cache_page(60*60))
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Con esto en mi entorno local de desarrollo pase de tiempo de respuesta de 600ms a 200ms.
En el cache_page se pasa la cantidad de segundos que se desea cachear la respuesta en mi respuesta está de 60 minutos.